# A/B testing parity (A=B)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ab-test, equivalence

I can't find any information on how to run an A/B test that shows that the new implementation B is likely at least as good as A. My metric is visitor conversion so I could use a test of proportions and compute a z-score to check if B is better than A. But I do not expect any lift. I just need to show B is as good as A with high confidence.

All I can think of is running a high-power (power = desired confidence) B/A test checking if A is better than B. Since I need a high-power test and would like to detect even a small lift, that requires a large (long running) test. If A shows no lift over B, I would have high confidence that B is at least as good as A.

Am I missing something? Is there a better approach? Thanks!

Comment: You are interested in *equivalence testing*, see questions tagged as [tag:equivalence] or [tag:tost].

Comment: Your phrasing "B is likely *at least as good* as A" also makes me think you're interested in *non-inferiority testing* (which is closely related to equivalence testing).

Comment: Yes, indeed. Specifically, I would like to calculate the sample size. I found this calculator: http://powerandsamplesize.com/Calculators/Compare-2-Proportions/2-Sample-Non-Inferiority-or-Superiority but I am not sure if I should enter the same pA and pB or not

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest to read Benavoli & Zaffalon (2017) "Time for a Change: A Tutorial for Comparing Multiple Classifiers Through Bayesian Analysis" [[PDF]](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjd_rWhuJLaAhVMyGMKHRBBC5kQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2F1606.04316&usg=AOvVaw2oLtOuIivMuEOd2R4H6nRO).

The paper introduces the problem of comparing two classifiers in different settings. Authors show how NHST (null hypothesis significance testing) falls short of expectations and proposes simple Bayesian alternatives (code included).

The case "what is the probability A = B?" is also covered. The paper is very readable.